# UJMP Java library for sparse matrix

Tags: java, matrix, sparse-matrix, ujmp

I have downloaded and included UJMP (Universal Java Matrix Package) library to my project for generating sparse matrix. But I could not find any documentation about functions of the library, how to create a sparse matrix, adding element to matrix etc. Is there anyone experienced about it or have a documentation about the library? Thank you for all.

Comment: http://en.sourceforge.jp/frs/g_redir.php?m=jaist&f=%2Fujmp%2Fujmp-complete%2F0.2.5%2Fujmp-complete-0.2.5-javadoc.zip for the javadoc

Answer (score 2):

There is a [la4j library](http://la4j.org/) that supports sparse matrices and vectors. Follow the examples given at official site. la4j supports [CRS (Compressed Row Storage)](http://netlib.org/linalg/html_templates/node91.html) as well as [CCS (Compressed Column Storage)](http://netlib.org/linalg/html_templates/node92.html) for sparse matrices. More importantly, the its actually taking the advantages from sparse data in computations due to easy-to-use composable iterators. For example, multiplication of two sparse matrices of shape 10k x 10k with just 1% of non-zero values will take a few microseconds on a modern laptop.

Here is the example:

```
Matrix a = CRSMatrix.random(10000, 10000, 0.25 /* density */, new Random());
Matrix b = CCSMatrix.random(10000, 10000, 0.25 /* density */, new Random());
Matrix c = a.multiply(b);
```

The la4j is actively developed. The current version [0.5.0](https://github.com/vkostyukov/la4j/releases/tag/0.5.0) has released in Jan 2015.