# UJMP documentation required

Tags: java, sparse-matrix, ujmp

I am using Intellj idea. I  heard about UJMP package to create sparse and dense Matrix. I need to create sparse matrix. For that I go to UJMP website. Download a zip file. After extract that a folder created `universal-java-matrix-package-master`. I copy paste that within my program src file. Then import this package in my program. Then write down the code from there documentation

```
Matrix sparse = SparseMatrix.Factory.zeros(4, 4);
sparse.setAsDouble(2.0, 0, 0);
```

But this is not working. Can any one guide me how to import UJMP package in my class file? What are the procedure and step involve with it? Which code used to create sparse matrix? I also read this link [UJMP Java library for sparse matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13207762/ujmp-java-library-for-sparse-matrix)  but don't think this one help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also faced the same problem. UJMP matrix does not have good documentation. Very few examples are there which doesn't give you proper idea. All you have to do Email those person who build this matrix class. There mail id is provided on there official website. If they read your problem they will help you. I also got help from them. To import ujmp package into your class file you should enable maven application.